# Dolphins using IBM translation machine and aliens stealing the ocean

Tags: story-identification, character-identification

I read a book on kindle unlimited back in 2014, at that point it was a two series set with more to come. In it, was two dolphins that were able to talk using a translation Matrix powered by IBM machines. I also remember a character called clay who was a military man. And I remember in one of the books, water was being stolen from the ocean by aliens. There was also an incident when a monkey was lost in the jungle  and they used the translation matrix for it too.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

It might be [Breakthrough by Michael C. Grumley](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18622809-breakthrough) and the associated Breakthrough series.

I'm not 100% sure, but this is a kindle unlimited book, one of the [Goodread reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1492121480?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) mentions "aliens stealing Earths water", and the synopsis includes:

> With the help of a powerful computer system, Alison Shaw and her team are preparing to translate the first two-way conversation with the planet's second smartest species.

Comment: Yes, I have the book and this is correct.The protagonist is naval investigator John Clay and the translation software (IMIS  - short for *InterMammal Interpretive System*) is built with the help of IBM.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! This has been bugging me for  a few weeks and no matter how many things I tried I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @MasonJay, I'm glad we could help. Would you mind clicking the checkmark beside the answer to confirm this was the correct book in case your comment ever gets lost in the future?